# Why is there no animation while rotating disclosure button?

Tags: uitableview, animation, rotation, reloaddata

My button rotates upon clicks in an animated way by using `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration:animations:`, however the button is not animating.

I'm trying to reimplement `UITableView`'s disclosure indicator. I am making my own because `UITableView`'s is not flexible enough. For example, I would like mine to be on the left, but this is not possible.

My disclosure button subclass *almost* works. It rotates correctly, but when it rotates there is no animation. It should goes from the non rotated to rotated; there is no animation in between.

```
#define DegreesToRadians(x) ((x) * M_PI / 180.0)

- (void)rotateToOpenPosition {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)DegreesToRadians(90))];
    }];
}

- (void)rotateToClosedPosition {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)DegreesToRadians(0))];
    }];
}
```

I'm also using Auto Layout in the nib that contain the UITableViewCell the disclosure button is in.
This might be related to the problem. Here are the constraints:

**EDIT:** This is most likely not the problem, as I tried removing auto layout from the same nib, and the problem still occurs.

[image: Autolayout constraints]

Why is it not rotating, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling `[tableView reloadData]` right after I called the methods to start animating the button.

Stupid.